# What's the word?

Tags: riddle, word

Take my prefix and it's a god.

Say that aloud and it's someplace people go.

The last two letters are quite popular among the youth.

But my last letter is something everyone needs to do, especially the elderly.

What word am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> **helistop**.

Take my prefix and it's a god.

> **Hel** is a Norse goddess.

Say that aloud and it's someplace people go.

> As in the expression "go to **hell**."

The last two letters are quite popular among the youth.

> **OP** is a popular abbreviation for "overpowered" in games or "original poster" on online forums.

But my last letter is something everyone needs to do, especially the elderly.

> The letter **p** can stand for urination, which everyone needs to do, and it is not uncommon to urinate more frequently with age.